# Existence of particular functionals in a family of linear functionals

Tags: functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

Let $U\subset B$ be a subset of a Banach space $B$, and let $D$ be a complete topological vector space. I have given a family $\mathcal L(U)=\{L_u\ |\ u\in U\}$ of linear functionals $L_u:D\to\mathbb R$ and a function $c:D\to[0,\infty)$ such that
\begin{align*}
|L_u(x)-L_v(x)|\leq c(x)||u-v||\qquad\forall u,v\in B,x\in D.
\end{align*}
 The question now is:

**Is there any chance of deciding whether $\mathcal L(U)$ contains the zero functional?**
(i.e. is there some $u\in U$ such that $L_u(x)=0$ for each $x\in D$?)

In particular,

1. which (additional) conditions have to be satisfied? Or
2. how must $U$ or even $D$ look like?

Any hints or suggestions are highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there more information about $L_u$?

Comment: I added what I know for the moment. Does this help?

Comment: The set does not contain the zero functional if for instance $U=\emptyset$ or $L_u = f \ne0$ for all $u\in U$ with $f\in D^*$.

Comment: Yes, these are nice (trivial) examples. But I'am more interested in finding criteria which guarantee that the family contains the zero functional.

Comment: What is the mapping $u\mapsto L_u$?

Comment: I don't know. This can be any arbitrary mapping, not necessarily linear.